# SQL Server TRUNCATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, truncate

I have a question to the `TRUNCATE` command.

How does `TRUNCATE` work in background ?

I read a text that says `TRUNCATE` creates a copy from the table and then start to delete all rows of the table. Is it correct?

Comment: Can you provide a link to this text you read so that someone might correct them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the information from [here](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/05/09/the-difference-in-truncate-and-delete-in-sql-server/)

TRUNCATE logs the deallocation of the data pages in which the data
exists which means that your data rows still actually exist in the data pages, but the extents have been marked as empty for reuse.  This is what
makes TRUNCATE a faster operation to perform over DELETE.

You cannot TRUNCATE a table that has any foreign key
constraints.  You will have to remove the contraints, TRUNCATE the
table, and reapply the contraints.

TRUNCATE will reset any identity columns to the default seed
value.  This means if you have a table with an identity column and
you have 264 rows with a seed value of 1, your last record will have
the value 264 (assuming you started with value 1) in its identity
columns.  After TRUNCATEing your table, when you insert a new
record into the empty table, the identity column will have a value of
1

Comment: To add a couple of additional considerations, `TRUNCATE` does not remove statistics; it is necessary to `UPDATE STATISTICS` afterward.  Space is reclaimed asynchronously by a background cleanup process so the space of large truncated tables may not be immediately available.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx.